# Resize image if filesize is over 50kb

Tags: php, image-manipulation

How do I resize an image if the image size is over 50 kb.

This is my current code.

```
$sess=66666;
$images = $_FILES["photoimg"]["tmp_name"];
$new_images = "$sess.gif";
$width=200; 
//*** Fix Width & Heigh (Autu caculate) ***//
$size=GetimageSize($images);
$height=round($width*$size[1]/$size[0]);
if($size[2] == 1) {
    $images_orig = imagecreatefromgif($images);
} else if($size[2] == 2) {
    $images_orig = imagecreatefromjpeg($images);
}else if($size[2] == 3) {
    $images_orig = imagecreatefrompng($images); 
}
$photoX = ImagesX($images_orig);
$photoY = ImagesY($images_orig);
$images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width+1, $height+1, $photoX, $photoY);
Imagejpeg($images_fin,"images/".$new_images);
ImageDestroy($images_orig);
ImageDestroy($images_fin);
```

Comment: I would suggest using a if and testing the size of the file in the condition... What have you tried ?

Comment: why are you using `Imagejpeg`, `GetimageSize`? PHP is case sensitive! Use [imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagejpeg.php), [getimagesize](http://au1.php.net/manual/ru/function.getimagesize.php) instead

so first of all put everything to lowercase and it might work

Comment: @vladkras - actually.... Function names are case insensitive.

Comment: @andrewsi and what about variable names?

Comment: @vladkras - variable names are case sensitive. It's one of the more confusingly designed parts of PHP - I wish they'd kept some consistency.

Comment: @andrewsi OMG, I know it!

Answer (score 4):

Use `filesize()`.

```
$sess=66666;
$images = $_FILES["photoimg"]["tmp_name"];
$new_images = "$sess.gif";
$maxsize = 50 * 1024; // 50Kb

if( filesize($images) > $maxsize) {
    $width=200; 
    //*** Fix Width & Heigh (Autu caculate) ***//
    $size=getimagesize($images);
    $height=round($width*$size[1]/$size[0]);
    if($size[2] == 1) {
        $images_orig = imagecreatefromgif($images);
    } else if($size[2] == 2) {
        $images_orig = imagecreatefromjpeg($images);
    }else if($size[2] == 3) {
        $images_orig = imagecreatefrompng($images); 
    }
    $photoX = imagesx($images_orig);
    $photoY = imagesy($images_orig);
    $images_fin = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width+1, $height+1,         $photoX, $photoY);
    imagejpeg($images_fin,"images/".$new_images);
    imagedestroy($images_orig);
    imagedestroy($images_fin);
} else {
    imagejpeg($images,"images/".$new_images);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Test file size like this :

```
$maxSize = 50 * 1024;

$sess=66666;
$images = $_FILES["photoimg"]["tmp_name"];

if(filesize($images) > $maxSize){

    $sess=66666;
    $images = $_FILES["photoimg"]["tmp_name"];
    $new_images = "$sess.gif";
    $width=200; 
    //*** Fix Width & Heigh (Autu caculate) ***//
    $size=GetimageSize($images);
    $height=round($width*$size[1]/$size[0]);
    if($size[2] == 1) {
        $images_orig = imagecreatefromgif($images);
    } else if($size[2] == 2) {
        $images_orig = imagecreatefromjpeg($images);
    }else if($size[2] == 3) {
        $images_orig = imagecreatefrompng($images); 
    }
    $photoX = ImagesX($images_orig);
    $photoY = ImagesY($images_orig);
    $images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
    ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width+1, $height+1, $photoX, $photoY);
    Imagejpeg($images_fin,"images/".$new_images);
    ImageDestroy($images_orig);
    ImageDestroy($images_fin);

}
```

Comment: When filesize is under 50kb the file isn't saved, and remains in temporary directory. Also 50Kb is 51200 bytes.  Also , please refrain from making a duplicate answer.

Comment: @TimDev I won't flag you because of your duplicate answer comment, because your comment is useful. However, please refrain from not looking at timestamps and blaming people for duplicate answers. On the timestamp you can clearly see he replied only 3 minutes after the other answer. I take ~10 minutes for each one of my answers, so it's doubtful he knew the other answer was there.